# Select specific words using awk while ignoring others

Tags: unix, awk

Let's say I have a very long file with species along with their occurrences. And I would like to keep species with some of those occurrences, in my case: CHU, NEU, RNE, SCR, TDF. For example, my original matrix is:

```
Species_A; CHU, NEU, TUC, SCR
Species_B; CHU, NEU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_C; COR, NEU, SAL, TDF
Species_D; CHU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_D; SCR, TDF
```

And I would like to keep only those species with the occurences CHU, NEU, RNE, SCR, TDF, while excluding the rest of the sites:

```
Species_B; CHU, NEU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_D; CHU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_D; SCR, TDF
```

I think one option could be:

awk -F ";" '$2 /CHU/ && /NEU/ && /RNE/ && /SCR/ && /TDF/ { print}' file

But this will also include those unwanted sites (e.g. SAL, TUC).

Any tip is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Awk Method 1: Regular expression

```
$ awk  '/;([[:blank:],]*(CHU|NEU|RNE|SCR|TDF))+$/' file
Species_B; CHU, NEU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_D; CHU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_D; SCR, TDF
```

This prints only those lines which match the regex `;([[:blank:],]*(CHU|NEU|RNE|SCR|TDF))+$`.

## Awk Method 2: Looping

Try:

```
$ awk  '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if (!($i~/^(CHU|NEU|RNE|SCR|TDF)/)) next} 1' file
Species_B; CHU, NEU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_D; CHU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_D; SCR, TDF
```

#### How it works

- `for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if (!($i~/^(CHU|NEU|RNE|SCR|TDF)/)) next`

  This loops through all words after the first.  If any one of those words does not begin with one of your approved 3-letter strings, then we skip the rest of the commands and jump to start over on the `next` line.
- `1`

  This is awk's shorthand for print-the-line.  (This, of course, is only executed if the `next` command above is not triggered.)

## Using sed

Using the same logic as for method 1:

```
$ sed -En  '/;([[:blank:],]*(CHU|NEU|RNE|SCR|TDF))+$/p' file
Species_B; CHU, NEU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_D; CHU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_D; SCR, TDF
```

## Using grep

Using the same regex logic:

```
$ grep -E  ';([[:blank:],]*(CHU|NEU|RNE|SCR|TDF))+$' file
Species_B; CHU, NEU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_D; CHU, RNE, SCR, TDF
Species_D; SCR, TDF
```